# BlackBerry OS 6: IOException:"peer refused the connection" on specified url

Tags: blackberry, ioexception, httpconnection

Calling

```
Connector.open("http://MySpecifiedURL.com;deviceside=true;apn=rim.net.gprs");
```

Throws `IOException`: "peer refused the connection".

This happens only with few specifies URLs, that used for web services and only on BlackBerry OS 6, on other OS versions (5.0 and 4.*) and with other URLs everything works correctly. Can somebody help me with understanding why this happens?

Answer (score 2):

A "peer refused the connection" error occurs when the server doesn't like something about the connection, i.e. you didn't supply the right userid/password to the APN, or there's nothing listening at that port. My first try would be to drop the apn= part of the connection string.

But if I were you, I would switch to using Versatile Monkey's [networking helper class](http://www.versatilemonkey.com/blog/index.php/2009/06/24/networking-helper-class/) which will find the best TCP connection path for the device, regardless of OS version. It will let you handle the cases where devices are paired with a BES or not, if Wi-Fi is available, etc. It's really easy to use and solves a lot of connectivity problems that BB developers face given the mix of devices out there with BES, BIS, Wi-Fi, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The definitive answer to this subject I found it in "Apress Begining Blackberry Development Nov.2009".

From page 186 to 190 more or less... they throw out a perfectly written code for this... you invoke this Method they define and it will return the extra parameters needed to make a proper request depending on the network availability.

I cannot paste the code here since that would be illegal.

Cheers!.